# pandas why does int64 - float64 column subtraction yield NaN's

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I am confused by the results of pandas subtraction of two columns. When I subtract two float64 and int64 columns it yields several NaN entries. Why is this happening? What could be the cause of this strange behavior?

**Final Updae:** As N.Wouda pointed out, my problem was that the index columns did not match.

```
Y_predd.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
Y_train_2.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
```

solved my problem

**Update 2**: It seems like my index columns don't match, which makes sense because they are both sampled from the same data frome. How can I "start fresh" with new index coluns?

**Update**: `Y_predd- Y_train_2.astype('float64')` also yields NaN values. I am confused why this did not raise an error.  They are the same size. Why could this be yielding NaN?

```
In [48]: Y_predd.size
Out[48]: 182527

In [49]: Y_train_2.astype('float64').size
Out[49]: 182527
```

Original documentation of error:

```
In [38]: Y_train_2
Out[38]: 
66419     0
2319      0
114195    0
217532    0
131687    0
144024    0
94055     0
143479    0
143124    0
49910     0
109278    0
215905    1
127311    0
150365    0
117866    0
28702     0
168111    0
64625     0
207180    0
14555     0
179268    0
22021     1
120169    0
218769    0
259754    0
188296    1
63503     1
175104    0
218261    0
35453     0
         ..
112048    0
97294     0
68569     0
60333     0
184119    1
57632     0
153729    1
155353    0
114979    1
180634    0
42842     0
99979     0
243728    0
203679    0
244381    0
55646     0
35557     0
148977    0
164008    0
53227     1
219863    0
4625      0
155759    0
232463    0
167807    0
123638    0
230463    1
198219    0
128459    1
53911     0
Name: objective_for_classifier, dtype: int64

In [39]: Y_predd
Out[39]: 
0         0.00
1         0.48
2         0.04
3         0.00
4         0.48
5         0.58
6         0.00
7         0.00
8         0.02
9         0.06
10        0.22
11        0.32
12        0.12
13        0.26
14        0.18
15        0.18
16        0.28
17        0.30
18        0.52
19        0.32
20        0.38
21        0.00
22        0.02
23        0.00
24        0.22
25        0.64
26        0.30
27        0.76
28        0.10
29        0.42
          ... 
182497    0.60
182498    0.00
182499    0.06
182500    0.12
182501    0.00
182502    0.40
182503    0.70
182504    0.42
182505    0.54
182506    0.24
182507    0.56
182508    0.34
182509    0.10
182510    0.18
182511    0.06
182512    0.12
182513    0.00
182514    0.22
182515    0.08
182516    0.22
182517    0.00
182518    0.42
182519    0.02
182520    0.50
182521    0.00
182522    0.08
182523    0.16
182524    0.00
182525    0.32
182526    0.06
Name: prediction_method_used, dtype: float64

In [40]: Y_predd - Y_tr
Y_train_1  Y_train_2  

In [40]: Y_predd - Y_train_2
Out[41]: 
0          NaN
1          NaN
2         0.04
3          NaN
4         0.48
5          NaN
6         0.00
7         0.00
8          NaN
9          NaN
10         NaN
11        0.32
12       -0.88
13       -0.74
14        0.18
15         NaN
16         NaN
17         NaN
18         NaN
19        0.32
20        0.38
21        0.00
22        0.02
23        0.00
24        0.22
25         NaN
26        0.30
27         NaN
28        0.10
29        0.42
          ... 
260705     NaN
260706     NaN
260709     NaN
260710     NaN
260711     NaN
260713     NaN
260715     NaN
260716     NaN
260718     NaN
260721     NaN
260722     NaN
260723     NaN
260724     NaN
260725     NaN
260726     NaN
260727     NaN
260731     NaN
260735     NaN
260737     NaN
260738     NaN
260739     NaN
260740     NaN
260742     NaN
260743     NaN
260745     NaN
260748     NaN
260749     NaN
260750     NaN
260751     NaN
260752     NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Have you tried casting your int column to float and subtracting only similar data types?

Comment: Are you sure each dataframe has the same index range?

Comment: @sobek yes this also fails.

Comment: @N.Wouda How can I remove my index and start fresh? This problem seems to because both of these were originally sampled from a single data set.

Comment: @kilojoules There's [`reset_index` for dataframes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`reset_index` for Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) to remove the index.

Comment: Are you sure you want to drop the index? If these are bootstrap resamples, and you're subtracting predictions from training observations, as it looks like, you want to perform that operation on the same observations. The NaNs may be telling you that you have predictions for observations that don't appear in one of your resample folds.

Comment: @AdamAcosta thank you for the keen observation. I am bootstrapping, and the indexes should have lined up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting here so we can close the question, from the comments:

*Are you sure each dataframe has the same index range?*

You can reset the indices on both frames by `df.reset_index(drop=True)` and then subtract the frames as you were already doing. This process should result in the desired output.